# Application hangs at WMI Connect

Tags: c#, powershell

I use this piece of code to get the woner of a process on a remote computer.
The code runs fine for 99,9% of the time, but sometimes it keeps hanging on `scope.Connect()`, even though I specify a timeout of 10 seconds.

Does anybody knows how to prevent this WMI hangup?

Code:

```cs
// Configure the connection settings.
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", machine));
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);

// Try and connect to the remote (or local) machine.
try {
    scope.Connect();
} catch (ManagementException ex) {
    // Failed to authenticate properly.
    return "Failed to authenticate: " + ex.Message;
} catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) {
    // Unable to connect to the RPC service on the remote machine.
    return "Unable to connect to RPC service";
} catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException) {
    // User not authorized.
    return "Error: Unauthorized access";
}
```

Interesting enough I found out on which remote PC this code hangs. I tried t connect to it with PowerShell and PowerShell hangs too!
I used this code for that:

```psh
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName pcname
```

Comment: Something seems to be amiss with WMI on that particular host. I suggest you investigate that further and fix the problem at the source.

Comment: I agree that something is wrong on that host, but the question is: How can I prevent this from hanging up my application (or powershell script).

Comment: Try `telnet <host IP> -p 135` on a host you don't have problems connecting to and then try it on the host that makes your code hang. This will help you confirm a WMI client/network problem with that problematic host.

Comment: That's actually quite a good idea. To check on the port where WMI is talking to... Is WMI only talking on port 135?

Comment: I think so, unless some changes were done to the registry.

Comment: Successful connection to TCP port 135 doesn't guarantee that WMI isn't broken--for example, the connection may complete, but the database might be corrupt. Your best option is to fix WMI on the broken host.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : Indeed, this is true. Again I have a host with broken WMI. Telnet on port 135 works, but WMI does not... So anybody else have an idea how to check on a remote host if WMI is broken? Without having to make a WMI connection, because that will hang....

Comment: The fastest solution is to fix WMI on that host. There is not a "tell me if WMI is broken" command or API (that I know of) because it is usually assumed that WMI is a core OS component and should be functioning properly on a correctly configured machine.